# applescript Posix chaos

Tags: applescript, workflow, posix

Yet again flummoxed by syntax and ordering of an applescript workflow solution

When I create the following code

```
tell application "Finder"
    set remote_p to alias (POSIX file '/Volumes/WAM XSAN/Audio/AAA)
    set main_folder to (make new folder at remote_p with properties {name:temp_name}) as     alias

end tell
```

Everything works fine. However, I need to create the main_folder in different locations dependent on the input "client_code" and "department", So i tried this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set x_san to "/Volumes/WAM XSAN/"
    set x_sannewpath to (x_san & department & "/" & client_code)
    set x_sanfolder to POSIX file x_sannewpath
    set remote_p to alias (POSIX file x_sanfolder)
    set main_folder to (make new folder at remote_p with properties {name:temp_name}) as     alias

end tell
```

And the error comes back "Can't get "Volumes/WAM XSAN/Audio/AAA" of Application Finder"

Where am i going wrong in setting up the POSIX paths?

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example. I tried to model it after what you're trying to do. Note that I have moved most of the code outside the Finder tell block of code. The Finder does not know the "posix file" command. That's an applescript command, not a Finder command. Also you don't need the Finder to set variables and add strings together. We can do all of that outside the Finder.

Even though it sometimes works when you have the "posix file" command inside a Finder tell block of code, it's always best if you only tell applications to do what they know how to do. You can find what an application knows how to do by looking in its applescript dictionary. Check the Finder dictionary and you will see that "posix file" is not one of its commands.

Anyway, this will create a folder on your desktop. I hope this helps.

```
set x_san to "/Users/hmcshane/"
set client_code to "Desktop"
set temp_name to "test folder"

set x_sannewpath to x_san & client_code
set applescript_x_sannewpath to POSIX file x_sannewpath

tell application "Finder"
    set main_folder to (make new folder at applescript_x_sannewpath with properties {name:temp_name}) as alias
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set department to "Audio"
set client_code to "AAA"
set temp_name to "New Folder"
set x_san to "Volumes/WAM XSAN/"
set x_sannewpath to x_san & department & "/" & client_code
tell application "Finder" to set main_folder to (make new folder at POSIX file x_sannewpath with properties {name:temp_name})
```

Comment: Thank you  this worked just as well. All about the position of the POSIX